# Graphical problem on 20.10

Tags: drivers

Can someone please help me. I have graphical glitches in my 20.04 system. I have tried clean formatting back to 20.04 from 20.10. But same problem. I do not have an graphics card. I use HDMI output from motherboard. It seems to be software based. I now got all kinds of bugs I didn't get before. Using 20.04. Gnome version 3.36.8 64 bit.

I have used the same hardware specs for a long time with no problems. But all crashed after the latest update in 20.10

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Thanks for replying. There is no external GPU in use. Only video memory integrated in motherboard. I will try to try my best to describe the issue graphically.

Comment: The HDMI port on your motherboard is connected to a GPU.  Please execute `sudo lshw -c video` and append your question with the results of that command, and if you can describe the glitches that may help as well.

Comment: This has to do with the -49 and -50 kernels. Try using -48. See my other answers regarding this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics processor (GPU) is part of the Xeon chipset, and unfortunately there are reports of a bug that has reportedly been fixed in Linux kernel 5.11 rc4, at lease according to people at [that other distribution](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1843274)

I don't think I can offer any assurances that anything I can tell you would make this better although supposedly Ubuntu 21.04 uses the newer kernel and ***may*** fix your problem.  Another alternative would be to use the 18.04 LTS version of Ubuntu, or to add a new graphics card to your system.

Comment: This has to do with the -49 and -50 kernels. See my other answers about this. I'm also following up on a possible fix with the **Displays** settings **Refresh rate**.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks!